# Update of image padding is not rendered

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

So I have this component which renders tiled image-thumbnails, wrapped in a containing div. I also have a settings-dialog where I can adjust the padding of the images. However, when the padding is updated and sent to (all) the component(s), the padding seem to be added to the respective DOM-elements, but the images aren't re-rendered with the adjusted padding. **I.e. the images doesn't resize within the div**.

The component, minus some in this setting arbitrary logic is the following:

```
class ImageThumbnailView extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // Constructor stuff
    }

    // Some methods
    // ........

    render(){
        let style = {
            width: this.props.width,
            'padding-bottom': this.props.width,
            'margin-bottom' : this.rowSpacing,
        };

        let imgstyle = {
            padding: this.state.padding
        }

        /* To no avail
        let imgstyle = {
            'padding-left': this.state.padding,
            'padding-top': this.state.padding,
            'padding-right': this.state.padding,
            'padding-bottom': this.state.padding
        }*/

        return (
            <div className="folder-thumbnail" style={style} onClick={this.handleClick} onContextMenu={this.handleContextMenu}>
                <img style={imgstyle} src={this.props.tree.thumbnail} onLoad={this.fadeIn}></img>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

The associated (S)CSS is the following:

```
div.folder-thumbnail {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;

    img {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        // z-index: -3;
    }

    &:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }
}
```

So I've tested for quite a bit now, and the following is now clear to me:

- The fault is not in the logic: The `this.state.padding` variable is updated appropriately.
- The render method is called every time I update the state.
- The style is properly added to the img-tag, as I can see it from Developer Tools.
- When updating the padding, if I change some variable which causes the image(s) to be resized in some other fashion, the padding is re-rendered as well.

Consequently I am not so sure this is a react problem. If it isn't I fear this has been answered before, but I couldn't find anything.

In advance, thanks!

**Edit:**

It seems the problem does not occur in Firefox, but does in Chrome.

Comment: What browser are you testing this on? Are you setting the padding to `px` or some other value?

Comment: Where do you set your initial `state` props?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan Yeah sorry I just updated which browser. It seems to occur in Chrome but not in Firefox. Well the variable `this.state.padding` contains an integer, which seems to be "automatically cast" to px when added as a style inline.

Comment: @Benvorth The constructor.